# How calculate the height of div with definition 'height=auto'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I need to calculate the height of this div with Javascript.

When i wrote this script:

```
function getMainDivHeight() {
    var num = document.getElementById('up_container').style.height;
    return num;
}
```

this script returns `auto`

I need the height of the div after it change.

Thanks ! ! !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the `offsetHeight` property:

```
function getMainDivHeight() { 
 var num = document.getElementById('up_container').offsetHeight; 
 return num; 
}
```